# How can I use Chrome Devtools to block certain network requests in my extension's background script?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, service-worker, web-extension

I'm writing an extension for Chrome. This extension has a [service worker (f.k.a. background script)](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/intro/mv3-overview/#service-workers) that makes a network request to a third-party service. However, I'd like to see what happens when this network request fails. **How can I block network requests from my service worker to a particular domain or URL?**

I know how to do so for content scripts or for ordinary in-page JavaScript; I'm asking specifically about service workers.

Comment: Open [devtools for background.js](/a/10258029) and switch it offline in the network panel.